# How does Passport (oAuth2) work with GraphQL (TypeGraphQL)?

Tags: node.js, passport.js, next.js, graphql-js

I am attempting to use the Google Strategy.

My goal is to have the user access to the restricted area of the React Next.js app by being authenticated only through the Google Sign in. This is based off the extension of their email being @SpecificDomain.com.

I have a component on the frontend that opens up a Google sign in window and returns the object with the access token. As I understand, I am then to forward this object to the my own backend (Apollo server, TypeGraphQL config).

My ApolloServer instance looks like this:

```
onst apolloServer = new ApolloServer({ schema,
context: async ({ req}) => {
    let token = null;
    let currentUser = null;

    try{
      token = req.headers.authorization;

      if(token){
        currentUser = await authenticate(token);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn(`Unable to authenticate using auth token: ${token}`);
    }

    return {
      currentUser,
      token
    }



} }) as any;
```

From inside the context I am attempting to verify the users access token by sending the token to another component where I am trying to use Passport which uses the Google oauth2 strategy to verify the user.

However, all the examples I see online are using Express middleware. I am wondering if there's any way to do it with just GraphQL?

I do not understand how I am meant to call this:

```
    passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID: googleCredentials.CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: googleCredentials.CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL: googleCredentials.redirect_uris[0]
},
function(accessToken : string, cb : any, refreshToken? : string, profile? : string) {
  const userOject = {accessToken, refreshToken, profile};
  return cb(null, userOject);
}
));
```

How do I pass a token into this?

I tried this too,

```
   export default function authenticateUser(token : string) {
  passport.authenticate('oauth2');

}
```

But passport.authenticate doesn't have any token parameters.

Could someone please give me some pointers or point the right way?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Settled with using Express to handle authentication.